# Обработка html страницы с данными

Tags: php, laravel

Всем добрый вечер.
Помогите разобраться с такой задачей.

Вкратце, делаю книгу рецептов.

Есть страница с редактированием/добавлением нового рецепта. 
Если пользователь хочет создать новый рецепт, тогда я просто возвращаю с сервера эту страницу с пустыми полями, но если пользователь хочет отредактировать существующий рецепт, тогда мне нужно показать эту же страницу, но с заполненными данными о том рецепте, который хочет отредактировать.

У меня будут браться данные с БД и я их передам на страницу и заполню, но если пользователь захочет просто добавить новый рецепт, тогда будет ошибка, так как данных нет.

Как можно это сделать?

Если что-то не понятно, задавайте вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере создаете две функции, скажем, create и edit. Из функции create просто возвращаете нужный view без каких-либо данных, а в edit выбираете из базы рецепт, по переданному id и передаете в тот же view. А в самом шаблоне в value указываете что-то вроде `{{ $recipe->title or '' }}`

Comment: С полями понятно, спасибо.

А вот у меня на странице есть поле со списком и мне нужно его прокрутить в foreach

Comment: `<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('title', optional($recipe)->title) }}" />`

Comment: а зачем тут old нужен?

Comment: Ну суть, главное, что помог разобраться.

Comment: `а зачем тут old нужен?`, а где он еще нужен как не в формах?

Comment: Список можно так вывести
`<select name="list">
  @foreach ($values as $key => $va)
     @if ($recipe->someProp == $key)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" selected>{{ $val }}</option>
     @else
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $val }}</option>
     @endif
  @endforeach
  </select>`